# Checking for User Subscription - Apple Auto-Renewing Subscriptions

Tags: ios, iphone, subscription

How can I check if a user is subscribed to my auto-renewing subscription through Apple?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check In App Purchase Auto Renewable Subscription is valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120177/how-to-check-in-app-purchase-auto-renewable-subscription-is-valid)

Answer (score 5):

Follow this guide from Apple on [Verifying an Auto-renewable Subscription Receipts.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW5)

Basically you verify a receipt with Apple's servers and they'll respond with info about that receipt including `expires_date`. You can use that date to tell whether a user's subscription is current.  Apple will also respond with the `latest_receipt` if there has been a renewal since the receipt you submitted. You **can not** however determine if the user has turned off auto-renewal until the term of the subscription ends, and either it renews or it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Implement Auto-Renewable Subcriptions,You have to implement InApp-Purchase using Store-Kit.  [InApp Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

if you want to check the active user then can use external api "Flurry Analytics". [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/) It gives the total analytical description of your app.