# Server required for auto-renewable subscriptions on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, auto-renewing

Can someone explain to me what is required for Auto-Renewable subscriptions on iOS?

I'm confused as to whether it requires a server-side component (built by myself)? Or can everything be handled within the app?

Comment: Maybe duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120177/how-to-check-in-app-purchase-auto-renewable-subscription-is-valid?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this issue is fully covered in apple docs even with pictures and schemas

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html

Briefly:

1)  You will need server-side if you want to make your subscriptions more flexible
(ex: to add more sub-ns while app is in appstore) In this case your app gets list of subscriptions from server

2) You will be able to check the correctness of a transaction using your server by sending the received receipt to Apple-server, and give users the content if only the receipt is valid.

Answer (score 4):

For the most basic setup, the answer is no, you don't need your own back end. Apple takes care of the money, and you can get the transaction status from apple in the app and unlock or lock whatever the user is paying for based on that information.